# PyCharm Notebook: Widget javascript not detected

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

This python code in the PyCharm notebook viewer produces the error:

> Widget Javascript not detected.  It may not be installed properly. Did you enable the widgetsnbextension? If not, then run "jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension"

Code:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display
text = widgets.Text()
display(text)
```

I did enable the extension with the suggested command from the error.

The code works from a web-based jupyter notebook session.  I have made sure that the PyCharm project interpreter is set to the same python 3.4 environment that works for the web notebook session.

Any Ideas?

Comment: It appears that only the web-based notebook can use ipywidgets since javascript is involved.    Am I right?  Are there any desktop based notebooks that can use ipywidgets?

Comment: That will take long time for pycharm I think to have this as a priority, If I were you, use [JupyterLab](http://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyCharm does not support these widgets.  Here's a link to their page discussing this.  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14534