# Jupyter notebook: Widget Javascript not detected

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Question:
I installed python3 and jupyter notebook using pip3 in MacOs 10.9.
When I try to run the widget it gives error that there is no javascript widget.
I have python3 and R kernels installed in Jupyter-notebook.

Code:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display
text = widgets.Text()
display(text)
text.on_submit('hello')
```

Error:

```
Widget Javascript not detected.  It may not be installed or enabled properly.
```

Attempts:

```
sudo -H pip3 install ipywidgets  
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade ipywidgets  
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
# restarted the computer.
```

The last command gives error.

```
[EnableNBExtensionApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization:
[EnableNBExtensionApp] CRITICAL | Unrecognized flag: '--py'
```

Note that in mac I have jupyter-nbextension command but the command:

```
jupyter-nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

does not work either.

But `jupyter nbextension enable widgetsnbextension` gives no error and also does nothing. The same error is popped in if I run the code.

Also,

```
import ipywidgets
ipywidgets.__version__
```

gives '6.0.0'.

Some notes:

```
which jupyter  
jupyter is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/jupyter
which jupyter-notebook
jupyter-notebook is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

Related links:

```
https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/541    
https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/32    
https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/131    
https://github.com/binder-project/binder/issues/83
```

How can I install widgets?
Do I need to install java separately ?

Comment: Answered here (bad news -- ipywidgets not supported by PyCharm):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106767/pycharm-notebook-widget-javascript-not-detected

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run the following command:
`jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension`, then restart the kernel in Jupyter should do the trick.

Comment: Enabling notebook extension is SUCCESSFUL, but , however, the module widgets still gives the error: Widget Javascript not detected.  It may not be installed or enabled properly. Can we also solve WIDGETS problem???

Comment: Your not just missing the ipywidgets? Try installing it by running: pip install ipywidgets

Comment: Thanks @chjortlund, `pip install ipywidgets ` helped for me

Comment: This works for python 3.10 with NO anaconda.

Answer (score 5):

The answer from chjortlund did not work for me because I don't have root rights. This solved it for me:

```
pip3 install --upgrade ipywidgets
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the following commands successfully with Jupyter, Mac OS, Python 3.6, and Anaconda. The first command gets the latest version of ipywidgets at this time (version 7.0).

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets

jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

Comment: Indeed, the conda-forge version of `ipywidgets` is newer and this solves the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me:

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and after running the command:`jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension`, the prompt should appear:

```
>Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...
```

`- Validating: ok`.
Refresh your jupyter notebook and the widgets worked.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way, at least it worked for me: reinstall the ipywidgets and widgetsextension and it should work.

```
pip uninstall ipywidgets widgetsnbextension

pip install ipywidgets

jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
```