# jupyter notebooks: How to enable widget javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a jupyter notebook in a virtualenv. But when starting it and creating a simple `ipywidgets` example I get the following error:

```
Widget Javascript not detected.  It may not be installed properly. Did you enable the widgetsnbextension? If not, then run "jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension"
```

The example code is here:

```
from ipywidgets import Button, HBox
from ipywidgets import *

button = Button()
button.description = "Test"
display(button)
```

I have run the following commands on the terminal:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
```

and I have restarted the notebook anew, and also saw the similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769068/jupyter-notebook-widget-javascript-not-detected) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351109/ipython-notebook-ipywidgets-does-not-show), but I still get the same error.

- python 2.7.12
- ipywidgets 5.2.2
- firefox 56.0
- ubuntu 16.04.3

I need to keep the `ipywidgets` version in order to test something.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

Make sure to remove anything that could be related to anything with `jupyter`, `notebook`, `ipywidgets` from the system configuration, and reinstall everything in your virtualenv. Then run this `enable` command, start the notebook and it should work...

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip install ipywidgets --upgrade
```

helped me

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 