# Jupyter Notebook is unable to access the Js from the local machine

Tags: python, nlp, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6

**Jupyter Notebook is unable to access the Js from the local machine.**

`jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension` isnt helping

nor any of the solutions from [Jupyter notebook: Widget Javascript not detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769068/jupyter-notebook-widget-javascript-not-detected)

Here is the code

```py
from fonduer.parser.models import Document, Sentence
from fonduer.candidates.models import Mention
from fonduer.candidates import MentionExtractor
from tqdm import tqdm as tqdm
docs = session.query(Document).all()

mention_extractor = MentionExtractor(
    session,
    [Part, Attr],
    [part_ngrams, attr_ngrams],
    [part_matcher, attr_matcher],
    parallelism=PARALLEL
)
mention_extractor.apply(docs)
print(f"Num Mentions: {session.query(Mention).count()}")
```

Here is the full error.

```
Full Error

Widget Javascript not detected.  It may not be installed or enabled properly.
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-9b2839fa1727> in <module>
     12     parallelism=PARALLEL
     13 )
---> 14 mention_extractor.apply(docs)
     15 print(f"Num Mentions: {session.query(Mention).count()}")

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fonduer/candidates/mentions.py in apply(self, docs, clear, parallelism, progress_bar)
    447             progress bar is measured per document.
    448         """
--> 449         super().apply(
    450             docs, clear=clear, parallelism=parallelism, progress_bar=progress_bar
    451         )

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fonduer/utils/udf.py in apply(self, doc_loader, clear, parallelism, progress_bar, **kwargs)
     71             logger.debug("Setting up progress bar...")
     72             if hasattr(doc_loader, "__len__"):
---> 73                 self.pb = tqdm(total=len(doc_loader))
     74             else:
     75                 logger.error("Could not determine size of progress bar")

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/notebook.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    251             display(self.container)
    252         self.disp = self.display
--> 253         self.colour = colour
    254 
    255         # Print initial bar state

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/notebook.py in colour(self, bar_color)
    210     def colour(self, bar_color):
    211         if hasattr(self, 'container'):
--> 212             self.container.children[-2].style.bar_color = bar_color
    213 
    214     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

AttributeError: 'FloatProgress' object has no attribute 'style'
```

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded tqdm, this worked for me

```
pip3 install tqdm==4.40.0
```